# How docker truncate image ID

Tags: linux, docker

I see docker id is sha256sum of JSON object,
But when I run command docker images, I see image id size is 12 digits. How docker trim 62 digit sha value to 12 digits.

Mainly I'm looking for that logic, so that I can use it in future as well to trim sha256 sizes.

Comment: As you said: It's just a truncation. It's a pure display thing (same with container ids, ...). It should show the first 12 (?) characters. All CLI-operatoins can also be executed with the full id.

Comment: If we do, for example, a `docker image inspect ...`, we will see the full id. Here's a little one-liner to extract the full image-id: `docker image inspect <short-id> | jq '.[0].Id' | sed 's/[^:]://g' | xargs`

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the first 12 digits of the hex representation of the hash.

It's trivial to extract the prefix with tools such as [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html).

Example:

```
$ docker images hello-world:latest
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
hello-world   latest    d2c94e258dcb   8 months ago   13.3kB
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' hello-world:latest
sha256:d2c94e258dcb3c5ac2798d32e1249e42ef01cba4841c2234249495f87264ac5a
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' hello-world:latest | cut -c8-19
d2c94e258dcb
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' d2c94e258dcb | cut -c8-19
d2c94e258dcb
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' d2c94e258dcb | cut -d: -f2 | cut -c-12
d2c94e258dcb
```